# ifelse statement. I expect an array in return

Tags: r

I have a simple ifelse statement. I expect result to be an array of length 6: c("known", ... ). But I am getting an array of length 1: "known"

```
x <- 6
ifelse(x > 5, rep("known", x), rep("unknown", x))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `?ifelse`. It returns:

> A vector of the same length and attributes (including dimensions and "class") as test

You want `if` and `else`:

```
if (x > 5) {
  rep("known", x)
} 
else
{
  rep("unknown", x)
}
```

Or you could use `dplyr::case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)

case_when(x > 5 ~ rep("known", x), 
          TRUE ~ rep("unknown", x))
```